# A good practice to work with dictionaries?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm starting do develop a game (AS3), and in one step, the participants have to type a word in one of 5 different available languages, and then that word is translated to the other 4.

For the sake of example:

- I choose the word "home" in English, and then these fields are filled:
- Spanish: casa
- Russian: домой
- German: Zuhause
- French: maison

So the question is, what would be the best approach to do it?, are there any downloadable dictionaries available for different languages?, or it would be better to feed from a web service?.

Also something to consider is that the translations shouldn't consist of more than one word.

I never worked with dictionaries before, so I'd rather investigate a bit instead of starting with the left foot. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very broad for stackoverflow.  It would probably be easiest to use a webservice unless you have an offline need.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use property file. This is best approach to do multi-languaged application.

Comment: This is not about multi-languaged applications. Or at least I don't think the same principles work in both apps or games.